# Function pointers in Rust using constrained generics

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to create a struct that looks like this:

```
struct MediaLibrary<B>
where
    B: Ord,
{
    root_dir: PathBuf,
    item_meta_fn: String,
    self_meta_fn: String,
    media_item_filter: fn(&Path) -> bool,
    media_item_sort_key: fn(&Path) -> B,
}
```

The last two fields are meant to be used as a predicate to test if a given path is a valid media file and to sort a vector of paths (using `sort_by_key`), respectively.

However, as it is right now, the design is inflexible: both functions are fixed to accept only `Path`. I'd like to be able to use `P: AsRef<Path>` as the stdlib uses for many of its file and path methods, but I'm not sure how to add this.

A number of the methods I've `impl`'d for `MediaLibrary` are already using `P: AsRef<Path>` for their arguments, so my gut feeling tells me that there would be conflicts.

Comment: Why must they be function pointers as opposed to closures?

Comment: Hi Shep, there's no reason for them to be! I'm unfamiliar with the type definitions for closures, would those be the `Fn`/`FnMut`/`FnOnce` traits?

Comment: That's right, and function pointers implement those traits natively, so they can be used in the same place. However, I'm not sure that either actually solve your problem.

Comment: Is there something tricky that I'm missing? It almost seems like I need a `where` within a `where`, something like: `media_item_filter: F where F: Fn(P) -> bool; where P: AsRef<Path>`

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, you cannot have a function pointer with a generic type, I don't even think such a construct is accepted by the Rust parser.

Furthermore, you cannot simply switch to extra type parameters on the struct as they would be unused by the struct itself:

```
struct MediaLibrary<F, P1, K, P2, B>
where
    F: Fn(P1) -> bool,
    P1: AsRef<Path>,
    K: Fn(P2) -> B,
    P2: AsRef<Path>,
    B: Ord,
{
    root_dir: PathBuf,
    item_meta_fn: String,
    self_meta_fn: String,
    media_item_filter: F,
    media_item_sort_key: K,
}
```

```
error[E0392]: parameter `P1` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:3:24
  |
3 | struct MediaLibrary<F, P1, K, P2, B>
  |                        ^^ unused type parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `P1` or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

Instead, you can choose to apply the constraints only on the functions where they are used:

```
struct MediaLibrary<F> {
    media_item_filter: F,
}

impl<F> MediaLibrary<F> {
    fn do_filter<P>(&self)
    where
        F: Fn(P) -> bool,
        P: AsRef<Path>,
    {}
}
```

As the message states, you could also use `PhantomData`.