# How do I create a vector of functions with generic type parameters?

Tags: rust

I have a few functions with the same generic type signature:

```
pub fn selection_sort<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T]) {}

pub fn insertion_sort<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T]) {}
```

I want to put them into a `Vec` or array so that I can iterate over them and run the same tests on them, as follows:

```
let mut sorters: Vec<fn<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T])> = Vec::new();
```

However I get this compiler error:

```
error: expected `(`, found `<`
 --> src/main.rs:8:28
  |
8 |     let mut sorters: Vec<fn<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T])> = Vec::new();
  |         -----------        ^
  |         |
  |         while parsing the type for `mut sorters`
```

How can I put these functions into a vector?  Is there a better approach to re-use tests against functions that satisfy this signature?

I'm using Rust 1.24.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a function pointer with a generic type. You will need to pick a specific type for `T`:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub fn selection_sort<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T]) {}

pub fn insertion_sort<T: Ord + Debug>(v: &mut [T]) {}

fn main() {
    let sorters_u8: &[fn(&mut [u8])] = &[selection_sort, insertion_sort];
    let sorters_bool: &[fn(&mut [bool])] = &[selection_sort, insertion_sort];
}
```

The intuition here is that a function pointer has to *point to something*. Until a specific type has been provided to the function, there isn't any actual code generated — the compiler cannot create an infinite number of functions just in case one of them is chosen later.

See also:

- [Vector of Generic Structs in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40064700/155423)
- [Function pointers in Rust using constrained generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47360392/155423)

Comment: Thanks!  I verified that it worked, and it was actually inline with my tests which were per-type anyway.