# How to convert a generic function into a function pointer with a reference parameter?

Tags: rust, function-pointers

```rust
pub fn remove_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<()>;
```

I am struggling to cast [`std::fs::remove_file`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_file.html) to a function pointer:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec84f20b637c39e20bfa3f284a44d5dc)

```rust
use std::{io, fs, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let _:  fn(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = &fs::remove_file;

    // let _: &dyn FnOnce(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = &fs::remove_file;
}
```

The error is the following:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:43
  |
4 |     let _:  fn(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = &fs::remove_file;
  |             ---------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found reference
  |             |
  |             expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r std::path::Path) -> std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>`
              found reference `&fn(_) -> std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error> {std::fs::remove_file::<_>}`
```

The problem might be with the `for<'r>` higher-order lifetimes requirement, but I don't know how to solve it.

How would I do it with a trait object? The following doesn't compile either:

```rust
let _: &dyn FnOnce(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = &fs::remove_file;
```

I know I can make a wrapper function around `fs::remove_file`, but I'd like to avoid that and get `fs::remove_file` to become a function pointer or trait object itself.

This is not a duplicate of this [Function pointers in Rust using constrained generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360392/function-pointers-in-rust-using-constrained-generics) as I'd like to get a function pointer to the concrete instantiation of `std::fs::remove_file` with `&Path` as a type parameter, but not to have a generic function pointer type.

I tried the following and it doesn't work either:

```rust
use std::{io, fs, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let _:  fn(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = &fs::remove_file::<&Path>;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't answer this question, I've added explanation for that

Comment: Note that `&fs::remove_file` is a function pointer **pointer**. You don't need the `&`.

Comment: Yup, also noticed that but I tried multiple variations and just posted what was the last one...

Comment: Why would you like to avoid the wrapper function or closure? It's not possible to do this without a wrapper, and I can't really see a downside of using a wrapper.

Comment: A would like to avoid the wrapper to decrease the verbosity. If the generic function accepts many parameters I'd need to enumerate them all in the wrapper. I also don't see a solution without it in this particular setup ;(

Comment: All you need is `|p| fs::remove_file(p)` in this case, which really isn't _that_ verbose. And you indeed can't do this without a wrapper – the types are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to get a function pointer to the concrete instantiation of `std::fs::remove_file` with `&Path` as a type parameter, but not to have a generic function pointer type.

This is the heart of the issue. A concrete instantiation will compile. For example:

```
let _ : fn(&'static Path) -> io::Result<()> = fs::remove_file::<&'static Path>;
let _ : fn(&'r Path) -> io::Result<()> = fs::remove_file::<&'r Path>;
let _ : fn(&'long Path) -> io::Result<()> = fs::remove_file::<&'short Path>;
```

What you are trying to do is coerce from `fs::remove_file` of type:

```
∀ P: AsRef<Path>, P → io::Result<()>
```

to the type:

```
∀ 'r, &'r Path → io::Result<()>
```

The function pointer type is still generic over the lifetime. I don't think there's a reason this coercion couldn't be done, but [Rust has some issues in this area](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36582).

The most straightforward workaround that Rust understands is to use a closure:

```
let _ : fn(&Path) -> io::Result<()> = |p| fs::remove_file(p);
```